# How to check for a certain text value with jQuery.validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using `jQuery.validate()` plugin to validate my website forms. What I am looking to do now is throw up an error when a text field contains a certain string.

For example, say the string to be matched is "penguin". If the user enters "I like penguins" there should be an error, whereas if the user enters anything without the word penguin in it, it should be accepted.

Is there a straightforward way to do this with validate? I just can't figure it out...

Thanks!

Comment: What you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/phkyzvgn/2/)

Use  Customized method to match text .

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("titlePenguin", function(value, element) 
{
    value  = $.trim(value.toLowerCase());
    if(this.optional(element) || /^((?!penguin).)*$/i.test(value))
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

},"error ");
```

Comment: this checks for exact value, no? don't think this is what the OP needs

Comment: nice! checks for exact value and for existence of value

Comment: @op : you can do +1 if it satisfies your question,Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much, excellent answer and I have been able to implement it successfully. :)

Answer (score 0):

Before submition of your form, you can perform a custom validation.

```
if ($("#myinput").val().toLowerCase().indexOf("penguin") >= 0)
{
    return false;
}
//submit the form;
```